# How do I stop plugins and themes from getting updated in a new plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, automatic-updates

I found this 2 filters to add in my `functions.php` of the Theme:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );

add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

But I need to do totally block the updates this to multiple WP sites. So I thought to build a plugin that I install where I need instead go every time to change function.php. But is possible to do that with the plugin?

Comment: I don't see why not. Have you tried it?

Comment: i added these in a normal php page, creating a standard plugin. for some work (wp tell me there is a new version and ask if i want update) but for others not

Comment: Well the code in your question doesn't include anything for Wordpress core, and you specifically don't mention anything eccept themes and plugins. So what's your actual question here? Whether you can add that code to a plugin? Or how to stop _all_ updates with a plugin? It's very important that you actually ask the question you want answered.

Comment: yes , sorry i was editing it. I expressed myself badly and notice after while while looking for other material about it. I'm only finding methods to disable auto updates, but I would need to block them for plugin and themes while my plug in is active. I hope it is clear now, sorry for my english

Comment: Ok, so back to my first question: Have you tried adding these methods to a simple plugin? If it doesn't work the way you expect, what isn't working?

Comment: yes i added these, but with my plugin activated i  can still update the plugins. i need to don't give it the chance to upgrade them, even clicking on upgrade when my plug in is activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to disallow updates of themes and updates at all.

If I'm right, then this is basically a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897044/wordpress-how-to-disable-plugin-update

Comment: I managed to get what I wanted by using parts in this thread, thanks